# Flutter Flame collision detection with obstacles

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm trying to build a game were I have a player and a tiled map with walls and obstacles, the player can move up, right, down, left and I want the player to not go trough the walls or obstacles.

I used the collision system of flutter flame to implement this but I have a bug that its killing me, let me explain the bug that i have with an example

Let's say that the player goes up and collides with a wall, then the player cannot move up anymore
but if he keep colliding with the top edge and start moving right or left he will go through the walls on the left or right when he reaches the edge

```
class Player extends SpriteComponent
    with CollisionCallbacks, HasGameRef<MobArena> {
  final MovementJoystick joystick;
  bool collided = false;
  double speed = 50;
  JoystickDirection collidedDirection = JoystickDirection.idle;

  Player({required this.joystick}) : super(size: Vector2.all(16));

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(RectangleHitbox());
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    if (!joystick.relativeDelta.isZero()) {
      switch (joystick.direction) {
        case JoystickDirection.up:
          if (collided && collidedDirection == JoystickDirection.up) {
            break;
          }

          position.y += (joystick.relativeDelta * speed * dt)[1];
          break;
        case JoystickDirection.right:
          if (collided && collidedDirection == JoystickDirection.right) {
            break;
          }
          position.x += (joystick.relativeDelta * speed * dt)[0];
          break;
        case JoystickDirection.down:
          if (collided && collidedDirection == JoystickDirection.down) {
            break;
          }
          position.y += (joystick.relativeDelta * speed * dt)[1];
          break;
        case JoystickDirection.left:
          if (collided && collidedDirection == JoystickDirection.left) {
            break;
          }
          position.x += (joystick.relativeDelta * speed * dt)[0];
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
    if (other is Obstacle && !collided) {
      collided = true;
      collidedDirection = joystick.direction;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onCollisionEnd(PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollisionEnd(other);

    collidedDirection = JoystickDirection.idle;
    collided = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this type of checking you will have to have a list of collision directions instead of only one, since it can collide from multiple directions at the same time.

In the `onCollsionEnd` you'll also have to remove the directions that it no longer collides with from that list.

To make it a bit more efficient, you can use `onCollisionStart` instead of `onCollision` for checking when you are starting to collide with a new wall.

Comment: This helped me a lot, I was able to get it working without any issue, tysm!

Comment: Glad to hear! I can recommend joining our Discord server for faster help in the future :)